# PHP Array Inside Function

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have declared an array assigned to a variable called $PHPFiles but when I try to do anything with the array inside the function such as printing it in the example below I am getting an error stating it is undefined, any help in trying to solve this would be appreciated as I have tried making the variable global and public with no luck.

```
<?php

$PHPFiles = array();

$PHPFiles[] = 'sql1.php';
$PHPFiles[] = 'sql2.php';
$PHPFiles[] = 'sql3.php';

function push($PHPFiles) {

print_r(array_values($PHPFiles));

}

push();

?>
```

Cheers,
Jamie

Comment: `function push($PHPFiles)` <-> `push();` notice something?

Comment: You need to pass the variable when you call the funcion

Comment: Make your function call this way: `push($PHPFiles);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `push` requires an argument `$PHPFiles`, use it like this:

```
push($PHPFiles);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php

$PHPFiles = array();

$PHPFiles[] = 'sql1.php';
$PHPFiles[] = 'sql2.php';
$PHPFiles[] = 'sql3.php';

function push($PHPFiles) {
  print_r(array_values($PHPFiles));
}
// here you were not passed the variable while calling the `push()` method
push($PHPFiles);

?>
```

Comment: What's the difference between your suggestion and that of Pedro Lobito?

Comment: its same, but when I answered this question after I saw there is also an answer came from Pedro Lobito